# Static blog generator with ability to add pictures

Tags: open-source, images, static-site-generator

I have been using static blogs for blogging since 2 years now but every time I have add pictures, it's extra work of uploading the image to a third party provider like imgur, copying the link, pasting in editor, adding markdown syntax followed by saving the file to commit and publish the blog post.

Are there are any static blog generators that have a better flow for this? I would appreciate it if the flow is completely browser based (such as the blog post composer being a client I can run with a server locally) or completely commandline (vim + something).

Comment: What is a 'static blog generator'?

Comment: A software that takes text files of say markdown format and generates a HTML website/blog out of it.

Comment: Why do you upload the image to a third-party ? Can't you throw it in an "assets" directory you most likely already have for your blog with your js and css ? You can then use relative URLs in your markdown.

Comment: Try [HEXO](http://hexo.io/docs/index.html) or [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). No third-party sites. Command-line interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

- Create a directory where you'll save all of your pictures (lets say `/images`).
- Put all of the images you want in that directory and host them there.
- Add the pictures using something like `![alternative text for the image]({{ site.url }}/images/image1.jpg)`

Comment: Because Sindhu S is using a Mac, it might be helpful to add some information about how easy it is to install Jekyll on a Mac using Homebrew and Ruby gems with `gem install jekyll bundler` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using **[Ghost](https://ghost.org)**. What is Ghost?

> **Ghost** is a simple, powerful publishing platform that allows you to share your stories with the world.

Ghost is just another blogging platform like *Jekyll* and *Octopress*. This platform supports **markdown blogging** with split-screen so you can get markdown preview (what you see is what you get) and exactly you don't need database (**static blog**). One thing you should know, Ghost is running under **NodeJS**. So, you must be install or deploy your blog on the right environment that supports NodeJS application.

Ability to add pictures?

Instead of markdown blogging (taken from [Ghost support](http://support.ghost.org/add-image-post/)), you can add an image on your blog easily without pasting your full link of your image. Press `Ctrl + Shift + I` then the markdown syntax for image will appear, just drag your image into the preview of your markdown. You may check out how it works [here](http://support.ghost.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Add-Image-Gif.gif) (GIF image).

So, what's next?

Last but not least, Ghost is **open-source** project.

- You can contribute to them at https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost or
- just download and run on your environment https://ghost.org/download/